Can I create an assignment based on contributing to Stack Overflow?
I teach a computer science course at a university, and I was considering creating a class assignment centered around contributing to Stack Overflow. Students would create accounts on Stack Overflow and write questions, answers, or edits. They would then show evidence of their contributions for me to grade.
Would this assignment be an acceptable use of Stack Overflow?
Return to FAQ index


This Q&A was written as a response to a recent crop of SO-related university assignments. For other school- or assignment-related problems, see:

Should I send students to Stack Overflow? for teachers encouraging students to come to Stack Overflow of their own accord.
How do I ask and answer homework questions? for the students themselves.



What about searches on the site? If your students need to achieve something and instead of writing a question, they find the answer because it has already been asked before, will they get better points for not needing to ask a question?

I am not actually creating this assignment, so I don’t know if this really matters.

You are considering creating an assignment, but you are not actually creating this assignment. Can you elaborate?

It's a hypothetical. I wrote this Q&A to be an artificial equivalent to How do I ask and answer homework questions? - I just thought framing it as "I am a teacher writing an assignment" made for a better question than "I've seen a lot of these assignments; are they okay?"

I'd imagine using a private team would be a better approach, so it can be used as a teaching tool without the students' attempts/practice etc being any kind of burden on the community while still having that Q&A structure.

@KevinB That or a discussion on Canvas/Google Classroom/Schoology/the teacher's digital classroom of choice, yes. I wouldn't mind having that in the answer if you wanted to edit.

"and I was considering creating a class assignment centered around contributing to Stack Overflow" - define, "contributing". Because if it means "posting questions" or "posting answers", students are generally not the ones that are really capable of doing so on this site. The site is already filled with student-level questions and has answered them. Students should be performing their own research and I can't help but make a point out of the fact that they have infinitely more information at their fingertips than I did when I was studying... I scouted second hand book stores regularly.

These kinds of assignments have a bit of a bad history. There's a lot that can go wrong with them. For example:

Some students will likely post low-quality contributions just for the credit. They may even post questions or answers that are plagiarized or written by generative AI tools. None of this is acceptable, and all of it creates more noise to users who are coming to this site for help.
Even the best-intentioned students are unlikely to be very successful without guidance. Stack Overflow has some pretty specific rules and best practices, which are documented in the extensive tour, Help Center, Meta Stack Overflow FAQ, and Meta Stack Exchange FAQ. This site is unlike most others on the Internet, so without reading those guides, it's really hard to be good at contributing here.
A great number of questions have been asked already, and many beginner questions have been asked many times. Therefore, even if someone cares about this assignment and reads through the guides, many of the questions they think of off the top of their head will be closed as duplicates. Asking students to contribute answers can cause similar problems. Though answers cannot be "closed" as duplicates, answers that are overly similar to ones that already exist still clutter the site, which could attract some backlash.

As such, a poorly-executed assignment will likely result in a large number of low-quality questions, answers, and edits. This low-quality "noise" clutters the site - and since Stack Overflow is mostly moderated by volunteers, those volunteers will have to spend time cleaning it up via downvotes, closure, and deletion. Some of this moderation might even make it harder to grade the assignment - particularly deletion, which hides the post entirely from everyone except the original poster and users with 10K or more reputation.
More philosophically, the idea behind a Stack Overflow-based assignment may be at odds with this site's core intentions. Our goal is to "build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming." A student who's contributing as an assignment for school is unlikely to share those intentions; the less-motivated ones won't try to uphold them at all, and even one who tries their best on the assignment will be trying to prove their knowledge to you, not necessarily to creating a lasting resource for the community.
To put it bluntly, Stack Overflow is not your sandbox. A lot of people have put a lot of time into making it a reliable, lasting source of programming information. If you're creating this assignment for any reason besides forwarding that goal, that's not gimmicky or creative - it's disrespectful to the volunteers who have to clean up the mess and disruptive to the many, many programmers who rely on this service in their daily lives.
If you have read all that but are still absolutely insistent on creating this assignment, please at least do the following:

Consider making the assignment optional, or even not graded. Otherwise, no matter how hard you try to encourage your students to contribute meaningfully, it is almost guaranteed that someone will post a low-effort, low-quality question or answer just to get it over with. This also helps with the duplicate problem since if a student's idea is taken, they just don't have to do the assignment.
Make sure you know what good content is beforehand. Look over the guides, read some good Q&As, and maybe even make some contributions yourself so you know what you should be telling your students to create. If you don't know what good content looks like, it'll be that much harder for your students to figure it out.
Spend some class time discussing what good content looks like on this site. The tour, Help Center (particularly the pinned articles), and FAQ mentioned above are all good places to start, but you should ideally go further than that - perhaps by showing examples of good Q&As or writing (not publishing!) one as practice.
Strongly encourage your students to do preliminary research before posting. If they're asking a question, tell them use the Stack Overflow search feature and do some Google searches with site:stackoverflow.com - that narrows their results to posts from this site. If they're answering, tell them to scroll through all the answers to their question of choice to make sure nobody else has said the same thing.
Monitor their contributions. If something goes wrong, all the volunteers at Stack Overflow will have a bad time until you personally step in and do something. Look over their posts as soon as you can to make sure they understand the site, and talk to them if they don't. Consider monitoring Meta Stack Overflow for volunteers' complaints about the assignment as well - we notice when this sort of thing happens, and we complain loudly.

Most of all, remember - if your students' posts are getting downvoted, closed, or deleted, or if they're attracting angry comments from more-experienced volunteers, that's just as much your fault as it is theirs. It is your job to teach your students how to use this site responsibly. If you're not willing to put in the effort, please don't try.

The other answer suggests: "maybe even make some contributions yourself so you know what you should be telling your students to create". I would make a much stronger statement.
If you are teaching at university level then you should have expertise in your subject. For example, if you have barely done any programming, it would be absurd for you to teach programming at a university. You have to be substantially better at programming than someone who gets an A on your course, otherwise you aren't competent to teach or assess them.
Likewise, if you want to teach Stack Overflow, you should have expertise in Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is a complex community with particular standards and procedures. If you want to teach your students how to contribute, that's great! But in that case it's absolutely necessary that you become an expert yourself first, if you aren't already. I just can't imagine that someone could effectively and usefully teach students how to contribute here, if they hadn't already learned how to do so themselves through experience.
